# Javascript string.replace. Combining several .replace commands

Tags: javascript

I am working on an assignment using javascript but I am stuck on a problem.
When I try to join together several .replace commands i do not get the expected output. I do not use any libraries like Jquery.

```
var str = ('abc abc');
str = str.replace(/a/g, 'b').replace(/b/g, 'c');

alert(str);
```

With my code I get this output: ccc ccc. When I should get this: bcc bcc.

Can anyone see what I am doing wrong?

Best regards, a student from Norway :)

Comment: What you *should* get is exactly what you get. ;-) What you *want* to get might be different though. :-o

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Like @elclarns said, switch the replace functions so you are replacing b with c first.

```
str = str.replace(/b/g, 'c').replace(/a/g, 'b');
```

Comment: Thanks for the example! Can you explain why it is like that?

Comment: @user2926446, because code above executes left to right. second replace gets called on the result of the first replace.